# How to validate a form with ref in Vue Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

With the `Options API`, I validated my form like this:

template:

```html
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation @submit.prevent>
...
```

script:

```js
methods: {
  validate() {
    this.$refs.form.validate();
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, with new `Composition API`, how I can call `validate()` on form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, setup your [template ref](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#template-refs) by declaring a `ref` with the same name as used in the template (1️⃣). Then, return a `validate` method from your `setup()` (2️⃣):

```html
<template>
  <v-form ref="myForm">...</v-form>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  setup() {
    const myForm = ref(null)  // 1️⃣

    return {
      myForm, // 1️⃣

      validate() { // 2️⃣
        myForm.value.validate()
      },
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Binding methods with Vue Composition API]

Answer (score 4):

**Vue 2 + composition api :**

You could get access to that ref via the `context` which is the second parameter of the `setup` function:

```html
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation @submit.prevent="validate">
```

script :

```js
export default {
  setup(props,context) {
    functions validate() { 
       context.refs.form.validate()
      }

    return {
       validate
    }
  }
}
```

or destruct that context inside the parameter :

```js
export default {
  setup(props,{refs}) {
    functions validate() { 
      refs.form.validate()
      }

    return {
       validate
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this in `<script setup>` ? Specially if the validate function runs as part of a larger `submit` function

Comment: @CesarMartinezDominguez please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889935/8172857