# Calling method on Child Component - Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a parent component where I need to call a method that exists in one of its child components:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="callChildMethod">
    <child-component ref="child" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  setup(props) {
    const child = ref(null)
    const callChildMethod = () => {
      child.doSomething()
    }

    return {
      child,
      callChildMethod
    }
  }
</script>
```

The child component contains the `doSomething` method:

```
const doSomething = () => { console.log('calling method....') }
```

Since I'm using the VueJS3 and  the Composition API, my approach was to use a [template ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs) to call the method in the child component. Obviously is not working but I can't see what I'm missing. Does someone have a clue about this one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're missing the value field in your `ref`, it should be :

```
 const callChildMethod = () = {
  child.value.doSomething()
}
```

[image: Edit amazing-cori-5hgi9]

If the child component is defined using the script setup syntax you should use [defineExpose](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) to expose the method to the outside

```html
<script setup>

function doSomething(){
  //......
}

defineExpose({
  doSomething,
});

</script>
```

Parent :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="callChildMethod">
    <child-component ref="child" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  setup(props) {
    const child = ref(null)
    const callChildMethod = () => {
      child.doSomething()
    }

    return {
      child,
      callChildMethod
    }
  }
</scrip>
```

or

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="callChildMethod">
    <child-component ref="child" />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>

    const child = ref(null)
    const callChildMethod = () => {
      child.doSomething()
    }


</scrip>
```

Comment: The function statement const callChildMethod = () = { should be const callChildMethod = () => { in that whay it becomes an arrow-function

Comment: Getting an error "child.doSomething is not a function", on latest https://play.vuejs.org

Answer (score 58):

P.s. for `<script setup>` (Composition API)
need to use `defineExpose`

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

Parent component:

```
<script setup>
...
const childred = ref();

childred.value.doSomething()
</script>

<template>
  <ChildrenComponent ref="childred" />
</template>
```

ChildrenComponent:

```
<script setup>
...
function doSomething(){
  console.log(1);
}

defineExpose({
  doSomething,
});

</script>

<template>
  <div>123</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Great, when using script setup syntax just we have to do this way

Comment: thanks a lot man! All day I was searching for a solution. nobody mentioned defineExpose!!!! you are the best!!!!!!!

Comment: Seems not working on Vue 3 5.0.8 Composition API <script setup>, error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'doSomething')

Comment: @BassemRamzy seems like a problem with your components

Comment: @BassemRamzy I had exactly the same problem. The only way I made it work was to inspect the ref object and I found that you can call the function from childred.value.$.exposed.doSomething()

Answer (score 1):

Using `ref` generates an error with me, I found out another handshaking way (*using `watch` for a property set by a reactive variable in parent, emitting back the results*) that's fine with me, and gives more control, in case needed:

### Child Component:

```
const props = defineProps({
  callRequested: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
});
function myFunc() {
  let result = false ;
  // Do your stuff
  return result;
}
const emit = defineEmits(['funcResult']);
watch(
  () => props.callRequested,
  (newVal) => {
    console.log(`newVal is: ${newVal}`);
    if (newVal)
      emit('funcResult', myFunc());
  }
)
```

### Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="callChildMethod">
    <child-component 
     :call-requested="state.callRequested" 
     :@func-result="funcResult"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const state = reactive({
  callRequested: false,
});
function callChildMethod() {
  state.callRequested= true;
}
function funcResult(param) {
  state.callRequested = false;  // Reset it for next call
  // Do parent stuff based on param = function result
}
</script>
```

Comment: `ref` worked with me only after I `defineExpose` a variable (in addition to the function).