# defineExpose from component's <script setup> not working in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup, subcomponent

New to Vue in general and currently using 3.2.37, I possibly missunderstood the correct usage of composition api’s defineExpose directive as documented here: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

There are also some threads to be found, explaining how to expose members from inside `<script setup>` like [Calling method on Child Component - Composition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889756/calling-method-on-child-component-composition-api/70228978#70228978). But somehow I cannot manage to expose the `version` constant ref from child component `HelloWorld` so that it's `version` can be interpolated in `app` component.

app.vue:

```html
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <HelloWorld />
    <h1>version:{{HelloWorld.version}}</h1>
  </main>
</template>
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const version = ref('1.0.0');

defineExpose({ version });
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h3> You’ve successfully created a project with Vue.js and Vuetify. </h3>
    </div>
</template>
```

Image:
[version 1.0.0 not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcJr4.png)

Answer (score 15):

`defineExpose()` exposes properties on a component's [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs), not on the component definition imported from the `.vue` file.

`<App>` could use a computed prop to access `<HelloWorld>`'s exposed `version` prop:

1. Apply a template ref on `<HelloWorld>`:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<HelloWorld ref="helloWorldRef" />
```

2. Create a `ref` with the same name as the template ref:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const helloWorldRef = ref(null)
</script>
```

3. Create a computed prop that returns `<HelloWorld>`'s exposed `version` prop. Make sure to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (or a `null`-check) on `helloWorldRef.value`, as it's initially `null`:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const version = computed(() => helloWorldRef.value?.version)
</script>

<template>
  ⋮
  <h1>version:{{ version }}</h1>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-access-exposed-prop?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 6):

you can check this [website](https://mokkapps.de/vue-tips/expose-properties-in-a-script-setup-component/)...

Components using Options API or Composition API without  are open by default.

If we try to access the public instance of such a component via template ref or $parent chains, it will not expose any of the bindings declared inside the  block.

We can use the defineExpose compiler macro to explicitly expose properties:

**Child.vue**

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const foo = ref('foo')
const bar = ref('bar')
defineExpose({
  foo,
  bar,
})
</script>
```

When a parent gets an instance of Child.vue via template ref, the retrieved instance will be of the shape { foo: string, bar: string } (refs are automatically unwrapped just like on normal instances):

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <Child ref="child" />
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const child = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(child.value.foo)
  console.log(child.value.bar)
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An object of DOM elements and component instances, registered via template refs.

You can do it this way.

```
<HelloWorld ref="hello" />
<h1>version:{{ $refs.hello.version }}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you, that results in: App.vue:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')